# I can’t use mmap to share a Hash between processes

Tags: mmap, crystal-lang

I am implementing a multi-process library that provides a data structure for shared memory.
But I am having trouble now, I modified the shared Hash object in the child process, but the parent process still has not read the changed value.

Sample code: https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/6n34

Modified with the same pointer, why is it not effective?

Comment: Note that since `Hash` is a reference type, `sizeof(Hash(String, String))` will actually be the size of the pointer. You can use `instance_sizeof` to get the actual size of the referenced memory: https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/6nf1
But even then, the `Hash`' implementation has a pointers to some other memory, and that memory is not easily accessible..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you fork a process its memory is copied while retaining the same virtual memory addresses.

You're just putting a pointer into your shared memory section, so your memory layout before the fork is:

```
 +--------------------+    +--------------------+
 |    Shared memory   |    |     Parent heap    |
 |                    |    |                    |
 |                    |    |                    |
 |  Virtual address   |    |  +---------+       |
 |        of  --------------> | Hash    |       |
 |                    |    |  +---------+       |
 |                    |    |                    |
 +--------------------+    +--------------------+
```

After the fork the pointer is refering to each process' private memory respectively:

```
 +--------------------+    +--------------------+
 |    Shared memory   |    |     Parent heap    |
 |                    |    |                    |
 |                    |    |                    |
 |  Virtual address   |    |  +---------+       |
 |        of  --------------> | Hash    |       |
 |                 |  |    |  +---------+       |
 |                 |  |    |                    |
 +--------------------+    +--------------------+
                   |
                   |
                   |       +--------------------+
                   |       |     Child heap    |
                   |       |                    |
                   |       |                    |
                   |       |  +---------+       |
                   +--------> | Hash    |       |
                           |  +---------+       |
                           |                    |
                           +--------------------+
```

So when you dereference the pointer in the child, you're touching the object in the child heap only.

What you have to do instead is put all the actual data into the shared memory. This is tricky to do for standard Crystal datatypes, since they rely on being able to request new memory and have it managed by a garbage collector. So you would need to implement a GC that can work on shared memory.

However if you only have a fixed amount of data, say a couple of numbers or a fixed size string, you can utilize Crystal's value type to make the affair a little bit nicer:

```
module SharedMemory
  def self.create(type : T.class, size : Int32) forall T
    protection = LibC::PROT_READ | LibC::PROT_WRITE
    visibility = LibC::MAP_ANONYMOUS | LibC::MAP_SHARED
    ptr = LibC.mmap(nil, size * sizeof(T), protection, visibility, 0, 0).as(T*)
    Slice(T).new(ptr, size)
  end
end

record Data, point : Int32 do
  setter point
end

shared_data = SharedMemory.create(Data, 1)
shared_data[0] = Data.new 23

child = Process.fork
if child
  puts "Parent read: '#{shared_data[0].point}'"
  child.wait
  puts "Parent read: '#{shared_data[0].point}'"
else
  puts "Child read: '#{shared_data[0].point}'"
  # Slice#[] returns the object rather than a pointer to it, 
  # so given Data is a value type, it's copied to the local 
  # stack and the update wouldn't be visible in the shared memory section.
  # Therefore we need to get the pointer using Slice#to_unsafe 
  # and dereference it manually with Pointer#value
  shared_data.to_unsafe.value.point = 42
  puts "Child changed to: '#{shared_data[0].point}'"
end
```

```
Parent read: '23'
Child read: '23'
Child changed to: '42'
Parent read: '42'
```

https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/6nfn

The cavehat here is that you cannot put any `Reference` types like `String` or `Hash` into a struct, as then again these are just pointers into each process' private address space. Crystal provides types and API to make sharing for example a string a bit easier, namely `Slice` and `String#to_slice` etc., but you have to copy it to and from the shared memory each time you want to pass it or convert it back respectively, and you have to know your (maximum) string length in advance.